# CGFontCreateWithFontName(CFSTR("Times")) doesn't work, return NULL

Tags: iphone, macos, ipad, fonts

I'm trying to create font with font name/PostScript "Times" or "Times-Roman" or "Times-Bold" but function `CGFontCreateWithFontName` returns NULL. I also try `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times" size:18]`, but it's the same.

In my fonts library "Times" exists! So I got array `[UIFont familyNames]` and I discovered that there isn't "Times" family in the array!

How can I get "Times" font?

thanks

Comment: Is this a question for iOS (iPhone/iPad) or for Mac? They have different typography and typeface systems.

Comment: This is for iOS (iPad), and particularly "Times" is in group of 14 standard fonts for PDF document. It has to be!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPSMT" size:18]
```

There is a nice application called AllFonts on the appStore that helps you find out the same of every fonts.

Comment: TimesNewRomanPSMT probably work, but I need exactly "Times" font, and I don't think that it is the same. I need to "render" a PDF page with "Times" font and not "Times New Roman" font.

Comment: All right, then check the app I mentioned to see if that font exists, but I don't thing so ! ANd as for the difference between Times and Times new Roman, I rally think its the same !

Comment: I checked the app, Times there isn't... But if you look in your Mac library it there is. However Times and TimesNewRoman is not really the same, and when I parse a PDF document and it gives me font like "Times-Roman" how can I create it? If document gives me "Times" I put "TimesNewRomanPSMT"; if "Times-Bold" --> "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT"; but for "Times-Roman" doesn't exist "TimesNewRomanPS-RomanMT". I can't belive that I can't create a simple "Times" font, it is in the 14 PDF standard fonts!